# Django image color detection function is not called

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a function that can detect the color of the image of each article but I'm having a hard time making it work correctly.

here is my code

**views.py**

```
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image

def article(request):
    context = {'article': Article.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'article.html', context)


def color_detection(request):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, None)
    image = article.image
    my_image = Image.open(image)
    by_color = defaultdict(int)
    for pixel in my_image.getdata():
        by_color[pixel] += 1
    total = 0
    for key, x in by_color.items(): #taking the elements of dict
        a = [i for i in key] #turning them into multiple lists
        if total <= 1: #taking the first list of the list of lists
            tuple_of_a = tuple(a) 
            print(tuple_of_a) #should return the color of one colored pixel of the image something like (r, g, b)
            context = {'color':tuple_of_a}
            total += 1
        else:
            break

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)

    [... other unrelated views ...]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.article, name="index"),
url(r'^$', views.color_detection, name='color_detection'),
[... unrelated urls ...]
]
```

**template.py**

```
{% for a in article %}
    [... unrelated html ...]
    <p>{{ a.color }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It's one of my first project in django as a beginner so my mistakes might be basic, but I don't understand why the color_detection() function is not called, if you see some other mistakes in the code feel free to point it out, it'll be really helpful.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would it be called? You can only have one view that responds to a request, and the URL is already caught by your index view. And even if it was called, which article would it be operating on? What do you expect get_object_or_404(Article, None) to do?

It seems that you are confused about what views do; they respond to a request, and only one view can be mapped to a specific URL. But actually, this is not a view at all; this is really a utility function that you call on a specific article object. So, it should be a *method* on the Article model; it then operates on the article that is already passed as `self`, and returns some data rather than trying to render a template:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ... fields and Meta ...

    def color_detection(self):
        image = self.image
        ...
        return tuple_of_a
```

Now your template can just do:

```
{% for a in article %}
    [... unrelated html ...]
    <p>{{ a.color_detection }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was confusing views and models. Didn't understood where to put my operation.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified a specific url for it, both "index" and "color_detection" are mapped to the root (`r'^$'`). Django will call the first view that matches the url pattern, in your case `views.article`.